# I keep getting error: incomparable types: int and string

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to let the user pick from the list and whatever option the user picks should display in the text area but i am having difficulty in achieving that!

I also keep getting an error saying incomperable types: `int` to `string`.

```
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

    public class Lab4Part3 extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

    JList<String> list;

        public Lab4Part3() {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            Container c = getContentPane();

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

            JLabel new1Label = new JLabel ("Choose your fav subject");
    //create a list with 10 choices
            String choices [] = {"GUI", "Maths", "Database", "Object Oriented", "Web Dev", "Networks", "Switching", "Routing", "accounting", "finance",};

             list = new JList<String>(choices);
            list.addListSelectionListener(this);
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
            panel1.add(new1Label);
            panel1.add(list);

            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setText("Response will appear here");
            panel2.add(ta);

            c.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            c.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            setSize(400,300);
            setVisible(true);


        }

            public static void main (String args [])  {


            Lab4Part3 myFrame = new Lab4Part3 ();
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


        }


    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {


    if (list.getSelectedIndex()==("GUI"))  {


            ta.setText("GUI");
    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (list.getSelectedIndex()==("GUI"))  {
```

should be replaced by

```
 if (list.getSelectedIndex()==0)  {
```

since `"GUI"` is the first value in your `choices` array.

A cleaner way would be to use a `Map<Integer,String>` where you associate index of choice to the `String` value.
In this way, if the order of choices changes in your UI, the listener stays valid in its processing.